# Finding the function for points in a 6-dimensional space

Tags: functions

If I have a set of points in 6-dimensional space (e.g. (x1,y1,z1,u1,v1,w1)), is it possible to find a function that would cross through all the points? If it is, can there be any number of points, say, 1000?

Comment: So point $A$ say, in $6$-D space is represented by $(x_1,y_1,z_1,u_1,v_1,w_1)$. Similarly for the remaining five points. You require a function $f(x,y,z,u,v,w)$ such that for all points $f$ is well defined?

Comment: @Bacon Yes, so if you could graph the points and the function as a line, the line would cross the points.

Comment: The short (un-satisfying answer) is yes.  Define $f(x_i, y_i,..., w_i)=f_i$ (whatever you want the value to be at that point for as many distinct $(x_i,...,w_i)$ as you want) and you have your function.  It could be 0 everywhere else, it could take random values everywhere else... or its domain could be only the points you chose.

Comment: My guess though, is you want a function which is continuous, maybe differentiable, and probably defined at more points than just those you specified... (but you should include this in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted a line then create 6 functions $f_x(t),f_y(t),..,f_w(t)$ that for certain t cross through $(x_1,y_1,...,w_1),...,(x_n,y_n,...,w_n)$

You can put $f_x(1)=x_1$ and $f_x(k)=x_k$ and so on...

$$f_x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)...(t-k+1)(t-k-1)...(t-n)}{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)...(k-k+1)(k-k-1)...(k-n)} x_k$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$f_w(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)...(t-k+1)(t-k-1)...(t-n)}{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)...(k-k+1)(k-k-1)...(k-n)} w_k$$

So $f(t)=(f_x(t),f_y(t),..,f_w(t))$

Answer (score 0):

$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)+(y-y_1)...(y-y_n)+......+(w-w_1)...(w-w_n)=0$

Comment: Hm, but you wanted a line?

Comment: Yes, although it doesnt have to be straight.